# Ideal way of using for loop in node

Tags: node.js, for-loop, web-scraping

I've written a very tiny script in `node.js` to check out how links can be passed to a function using loop.

I could see that I can do the same in two ways but can't figure out which way I should stick to, meaning which one is ideal and why?

One way: `for (link in links) {}`

```
var request = require('request');
var links = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 'https://github.com/request/request'];
for (link in links) {
    (function(url) {
        request(url, function() {
            console.log(url);
        });
    })(links[link]);
}
```

The other way: `for (const link of links) {}`

```
var request = require('request');
var links = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 'https://github.com/request/request'];
for (const link of links) {
    (function(url) {
        request(url, function() {
            console.log(url);
        });
    })(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ideal way or at least an universal ideal way of doing this, So i will point out the difference between these two.

In first for loop you are iterating the array as an object (in javascript array is an object which can traverse with indexes). But will create a global variable called link after the execution. So an unwanted variable and memory location is created.

Try `console.log(link)` after the execution.

The second for loop is introduced with ECMA Script 6 and won't create a global variable and is recommended. Because of the readability and the more control over your data, and link can be defined as `const` if you want. So it won't be modified inside the loop.

For `node.js` I guess second one may be perfect for most scenarios. But in `javascript`, the first one may be higher in performance wise, if you are compiling it from ES6 to ES5 and it is the case for most scenarios.